# calculate conservative interpolation of two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation, projection

G'day

Firstly, apologies for poor wording - I'm at a bit of a loss of how to describe this problem. I'm trying to calculate the conservative interpolation between two different vertical coordinate systems.

I have a vector of ocean transport values `Ts`, that describe the amount of transport at different depth values `S`. These depths are unevenly spaced (and `size(S)` is equal to `size(Ts)+1` as the values in `S` are the depths at the top and bottom over which the transport value applies). I want to interpolate(/project?) this onto a vector of regularly spaced depths `Z`, where each new transport value `Tz` is formed from the values of `Ts` but weighted by the amount of overlap.

I've drawn a picture of what I mean (sorry for the bad quality webcam picture) I want to go from `Ts1,Ts2.Ts3...TsN` (bottom lines) to `Tz1,Tz2,...TzN` (top lines). The locations in the x direction for these are `s0,s1,s2,...sN` and `z0,z1,z2,...zN`. An example of the 'weighted overlap' would be:

```
Tz1 = a/(s1-s0) Ts1 + b/(s2-s1) Ts2 + c/(s3-s2) Ts3
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are shown in the image as the length of overlap.

[image: interpolation example]

Some more details:

Example of `z` and `s` follow:

```
z = 0:5:720;
s = [222.69;...
   223.74
   225.67
   228.53
   232.39
   237.35
   243.56
   251.17
   260.41
    271.5
   284.73
   300.42
    318.9
   340.54
   365.69
   394.69
   427.78
   465.11
   506.62
   551.98
   600.54
    651.2];
```

Note that I'm free to define `z`, but not `s`. Typically, `z` will be bigger than `s` (i.e. the smallest value in `z` will be smaller than in `s`, while the largest value in `z` will be larger than in `s`).

Help or tips greatly appreciated. Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Is your data truly irregular spaced? Because it appear to just have a growth factor?

Comment: It is typically scaled with thinner layers at the start, thicker in the middle, and thinner towards the end. So, maybe not truly irregular, but certainly unevenly spaced. I will edit to make this clear.

Comment: I don't think there is a very easy solution. I would say, rely on a while (or for) loop with iterators for both arrays. The while loop goes block by block (like your a, b and c). So you increase one of the iterators in each pass of the loop.

Comment: Do you want `size(Tz)==size(Ts)`? Can we suppose `s==z` for the first and last values?

Comment: Because `z` is evenly spaced, while `s` is unevenly spaced, `size(z) =/= size(s)`. I can do a bit of manipulation to ensure that `z` (which I have the freedom to define) spans the min,max of `s`. (see edits to question)

Comment: I updated my answer without the use of `interp1` with the `previous` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy solution, as stated in the comments. I'll give it a go though :

**One hypothesis first : We assume `z0>s0`** in order for your problem to be defined.

The idea (for your example) would be to get to the array below :

```
1  (s1-z0)  s1-s0   Ts1
1  (s2-s1)  s2-s1   Ts2
1  (z1-s2)  s3-s2   Ts3
2  (s3-z1)  s3-s2   Ts3
2  (z2-s3)  s4-s3   Ts4
3  (z3-z2)  s4-s3   Ts4
      ......
```

Then we would be able to compute, for each row : `column1*column3/column2` and then use `accumarray` to sum the results with respect to the indexes in the first column.

Now the hardest part is to get this array :

Suppose you have :

- A `Nx1` vectors `Ts`
- 2 `(N+1)x1` vectors `s` and `z`, with `z(1)>s(1)`.

  `Vectsz=sort([s(2:end);z]); % Sorted vector of s and z values`

In your case this vector should look like :

```
z0
s1
s2
z1
s3
z2
z3
...
```

The first column will serve as a subscript to apply `accumarray`, so we'll want it to increase each time there is a `z` value in our vector `Vectsz`

```
First=interp1(z,1:length(z),Vectsz,'previous');

Second=[diff(Vectsz);0]; % Padded with a 0 to keep the right size

Temp=diff(s);
Third=interp1(s(1:end-1),Temp,Vectsz,'previous');
```

This will just repeat the diff value everytime you have a z value in your vector `Vectsz`.

The last column is built exactly like the third one

```
Fourth=interp1(s(1:end-1),Ts,Vectsz,'previous');
```

Now that the array is built, a call to accumarray is enough to get the final result :

```
Res=accumarray(First,Second.*Fourth./Third);
```

### EDIT : There is actually no need for the use of `interp1` with the `previous` option :

```
Vectsz=sort([s(2:end);z]);

First=cumsum(ismember(Vectsz,z));

Second=[diff(Vectsz);0];

idx=cumsum(ismember(Vectsz,s(2:end)))+1;

Diffs=[diff(s);0];

Third=Diffs(idx);

Fourth=Ts(idx);

Res=accumarray(First,Second.*Fourth./Third);
```

Comment: I'm working through your answer, but stuck at Step 2: My version of matlab (R2013b) doesn't have the `previous` option for `interp1`. I've contacted IT to see about upgrading...

Comment: Second step can be replaced with : `First=cumsum(ismember(Vectsz,z))`

Comment: All in all I'll try to make this answer better, I don't like the look pf it

Comment: This is looking really good - one thing though, I tested it with `Ts=[1:22]';`, then checked to see if Ts was conserved, but `nansum(Ts)` =/= `nansum(Res)`. Any ideas?

Comment: also, if `z(1)>s(1)`, then `First(1)=0` and `accumarray` won't like that. I've chosen `z` so that `z(1)<s(1)`

Comment: Sorry, another comment. I tested with `Ts=[1:21]';`, and added `Vectsz(Vectsz>=s(end))=[];` after `Vectsz` is defined. I needed this since `size(Ts)` is equal to `size(s)-1`.
I'm also a little mystified by plotting up `Res` and `Ts` - They're quite different.

Comment: I think you answered the question by constructing the matrix `Res` correctly. I still have issues implementing your answer - but I think that's my issue. Cheers!